# I want to make 'restore point' for my Ubuntu 'SERVER' 18.04

Tags: server, restore

There is many topics about make restore point for Ubuntu 18.04.

But I can't find for Ubuntu server.
Since I don't use the GUI and will not use GUI, I have to do all my task in command line.

Is there any 'Systemback-like' program for Ubuntu Server 18.04??
(I read Systemback is only for below ubuntu 17.XX...)

Comment: humm... actually, `dd` command will do that right???